# Verify if file existes then moving file from sftp folder to another with C# (using Renci.SshNet.Sftp)

Tags: c#, ssis

I have this code in C# (script task SSIS)

```
    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        string Server = Dts.Variables["FTPServer"].Value.ToString();
        string User = Dts.Variables["FTPUser"].Value.ToString();
        string Password = Dts.Variables["FTPPassword"].Value.ToString();
        int port = (int) Dts.Variables["FTPPort"].Value;
        string remoteFolder = Dts.Variables["FTPRemoteFolder"].Value.ToString();
        string archiveFolder = remoteFolder + "/TEST_ARCHIVES/" ;
        moveFiles(Server, port, Password, User, remoteFolder, archiveFolder);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

    } 
    
    void moveFiles(string FTPServer,int port,string FTPPassword,string FTPUser,string oldPath,string newPath)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new SftpClient(FTPServer, port, FTPUser, FTPPassword))
                {
                    client.Connect();
                    if (!client.IsConnected)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Not Connected");
                    }
               List <SftpFile> files = (List<SftpFile>)client.ListDirectory(oldPath);
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if(file.Name.StartsWith("EXP_"))
                    {
                        file.MoveTo(newPath + file.Name );
                    }
                 
                }
                    client.Disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

The above script is from a script task SSIS and it can move files having name starts with "EXP_" from oldPath (folder 1 in sftp server)
to the newPath (folder 2 in sftp server).
It works fine correctly when the file does not exists in folder 2. But when I try to move a file that exists already in the newPath (folder 2 in sftp server) it fails when running the SSIS package.
What I need to implement :

- verify before if the file exists in folder 2
- move the file and if it exist already overwrite the old one with the new one

NB: I'm using in references : `using Renci.SshNet.Sftp;`
so the function `File.Exists()` not appear , it's a specific situation with functions that uses `Renci.SshNet.Sftp`

Answer (score 1):

MoveTo has an override that allows you to specify if it should overwrite the destination file, if it exists. Simply add a "true" to your file.MoveTo() call as a second parameter like this and give it a try:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    if(file.Name.StartsWith("EXP_"))
    {
        file.MoveTo(newPath + file.Name, true);
    }
}
```

See the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.moveto?view=net-6.0) for this method for more information.

Comment: adding argument is not supported for this function. As I said we talk about sftpfile class

Comment: I tried this code to verify if file exists in archive folder , it not make errors in syntaxe but when I execute the package i have the error , some the compare not achieved 
file.Name.ToString() != file_2.Name.ToString() and i tried also file.Name != file_2.Name

Comment: List <SftpFile> files = (List<SftpFile>)client.ListDirectory(oldPath);
                   List<SftpFile> files_archive = (List<SftpFile>)client.ListDirectory(newPath);
                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        if(file.Name.StartsWith("EXP_"))
                        {
                            foreach (var file_2 in files_archive)
                    {
                                if (file.Name.ToString() != file_2.Name.ToString())
                                    file.MoveTo(newPath + file.Name);
}}}

Comment: @AhmedMJ try to update your question with the new attempts you made

Comment: **Hello Experts, I found Solution** : i changed the list type to **<SftpFile>** and i used **Exists** function to check for existing files :
code C#    
List<SftpFile> files = (List<SftpFile>)client.ListDirectory(oldPath);
List<SftpFile> files_archive =(List<SftpFile>)client.ListDirectory(newPath);
foreach (SftpFile file in files)
{ // &&  !files_archive.Contains(file)
if (file.Name.StartsWith("EXP_"))
{
if (!files_archive.Exists(c => c.Name == file.Name))
file.MoveTo(newPath + file.Name);
 else
file.Delete();
}
}